# Connotation of dislike in 'Credit where credit is due'

Tags: idioms, connotation, idiom-meaning

I am a non-native speaker and I wonder whether or not there is a connotation of disagreement in the idiom `Credit where credit is due`

Would one say this only in a situation where a statement was creditworthy because it was profound but the user of the idiom disagrees with the actual statement?

I think so because of a [definition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/de/worterbuch/britisch/credit-where-credit-s-due) I found:

> an expression that means that you should praise someone who deserves it, although you might dislike some things about them:

I would like to hear a second opinion, though.

Comment: I remember an example from when I was in college. The professor told the class if even one sentence was found used from a source without crediting the source (known as 'citing the source') we would receive a failing grade.

Giving credit where credit is due is the same. If it's not mine it belongs to someone else. To credit a source is just and anything else is stealing.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, @FatherLuke, I think this is completely different from the idiom Sprottenwels is asking about. It clearly means "acknowledging what somebody has done", but the question is whether this is a grudging acknowledgment.

Comment: And here's why, @ColinFine, I think it does address his question. Sprottenwels is non english, asking about connotations:

> I am a non-native speaker ...

Giving credit where credit is due: Is this a begrudging obligation only?

Is how I read it.

Comment: @Father Luke OP actually asks two questions, the first of which is '... I wonder whether or not there is a connotation of disagreement in the idiom 'Credit where credit is due[?]' The answer to this is yes, there is a strong concessive connotation. This does not mean that it is not used where such a marking of grudgingness is not intended, but it does mean that care needs to be taken as most people will infer one without disambiguating context.

Comment: Crediting sources, which is what giving credit where credit is due, is acknowledging someone's contribution, whether begrudgingly or not. 

The key factor is the acknowledgement, not the attitude in which its given.

One might say, for example: Credit where credit was due was begrudgingly given.

Comment: At least in UK usage (see my reply) the idiom "credit where credit is due" has - or had -  nothing whatever to do with crediting sources. It is about giving acknowledment to the person or body you are talking about. Looking at the examples, I see that the phrase has been adopted (particularly in the US) to talk about crediting people's work, but this is a transferred meaning, and to me Sprottenwels' question is about the original meaning.

Comment: @FatherLuke - The phrase has nothing to do with "crediting sources".  Attempting to use the phrase where you should be crediting sources, in fact, could lead to reader confusion and a resulting failure to properly credit your sources.  (And, in the US, it does usually -- but not always -- carry a negative connotation.)

Comment: @HotLicks: Cite?

Comment: 66 years of living in the US, speaking English for about 65.

Comment: Mine comes from ...more reliable sources:

http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O214-creditwherecreditisduegiv.html

...although, to give credit where credit is due, I _am_ fifty six years old.

Comment: @FatherLuke - So show me a reference that has to do with "crediting sources" (as in a research paper).

Comment: @HotLicks. Nope. I cited an Encyclopedia. I gave a personal example. All I've seen from you was personal experience and you using numbers instead of words to tell me how old you are. 'This many fingers old' was good enough for me. You'll have to settle for my Encyclopedia reference. But I'm grateful for the opportunity. Thanks 'pard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having had a look at the phrase on [the Corpus of Global Web-based English](https://www.english-corpora.org/glowbe/), I find that there is a strong UK/US difference in this.

First, the use of the phrase *credit where credit is due* in an absolute sense (without a verb such as *give*, *take* or *deserve*) is far more common in UK English than US (65/137 as against 15/194). [Example: "Credit where credit is due, he's a good player."]

Secondly, the phrase is more likely to be used in the grudging sense that Sprottenwels refers to in UK than US English - my quick estimates are that around 25% of the US examples are clearly grudging, while more than half of UK examples have this connotation. (I have tried to be conservative, and take count them only when it is pretty clear that this sense is involve - there are probably more that I have rejected because there is not enough context to be certain).

I haven't looked at other varieties of English in the corpus.

**Edit**: Canadian English seems to be close to US, and Australian seems to be somewhere between US and UK in this respect.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it was the most useful, regarding the question's aspect of whether the idiom can be used grudgingly only.

Answer (score 4):

It's a general purpose adage.  You might say it grudgingly:

> I don't like John's attitude, but I have to give credit where credit
>   is due:  John did most of the work on the project.

or admiringly

> As much as I'd like the award, I have to give credit where credit is
>   due:  John should be the winner since it was his idea.

In any case, unless the speaker is being ironic, he will mean that the recognition is for something credit-worthy.

Comment: Yes; but I think Sprottenwels is right that the elliptic form _credit where credit is due_ (without a verb) is nearly always grudging.

Comment: @ColinFine I could be convinced by evidence.

Comment: Looking on GlobWE (the global corpus of web-based English), it seems partly to be a US/UK difference (I haven't yet looked at the other varieties.) The US instances of the phrase are overwhelmingly the full clause _give credit where credit is due_, and are at least as likely to be appreciative as grudging. It seems to me that the instances of the absolute (verbless) phrase is rather more common in UK English, and that use is more likely to be grudging. I will research further.

Comment: More information in my reply.

Answer (score 4):

I have always heard it as "to give credit where credit is due". Also, in my personal experience, it may be used without any connotation of disagreement. Sometimes it may be used by way of mild rebuke for a person or persons who have neglected to give a third party sufficient approbation or reward.

Here are some early examples.

> *What we complain of in the Recorder, is a spirit of too great captiousness and severity ; the want of giving credit where credit is due; a proneness to overlook.*
>   The Christian Journal, and Literary Register 1829
>
> *As it is but justice to give credit where credit is due, we would here observe that the conduct of Captain Lyon, of the steamboat Whitehall, justly entitles him to a large share.*
>   Extra Globe P.275, 
>    By Francis Preston Blair
>
> *Mr. Chairman, I think it is very important that we give credit where credit is due.*
>   Congressional Record, Volumes 1-53, 1874

and here some more recent examples

> *Standardizing procedures helps to diminish bias and promotes a higher code of fairness for giving credit where credit is due.*
>   Naked Management: Bare Essentials For Motivating The X-Generation At Work
>    By Marc H. Muchnick 1996
>
> *Attribution gives credit where credit is due, but only in a lumped sense when the paper cited has more than one author." If one knows enough of the way in which the research is being done, one can sometimes credit an individual*
>   Mathematical Modeling: A Chemical Engineer's Perspective  By Rutherford Aris 1999

**Conclusion**

In my opinion it is certainly possible to use the expression grudgingly or as oblique criticism, but it can also be used in a straightforward way to request justice.

Answer (score 0):

Christine Ammer, *The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms* (1997) has this comment about "give credit where credit is due" within a longer entry for "give credit":

> **give credit** ... **2.** Acknowledge an accomplishment, as in *They really should give her credit for the work she's done*. [Late 1700s] The phrase is sometimes amplified to **give credit where credit is due**, meaning the acknowledgment should be to the person who deserves it. This expression was probably coined by Samuel Adams in a letter (October 29, 1777), which put it: "Give credit to whom credit due." It is sometimes put **give someone their due**, as in *We should really give Nancy her due for trying to sort out this mess*.

As far as I can tell, nothing in Ammer's discussion above indicates dislike or hesitancy in the allocation of credit. But the entry for "credit where credit is due" in Judith Siefring, *The Oxford Dictionary of Idioms*, second edition (2004) has a very different tenor:

> **credit where credit is due** praise should be given when it is deserved, even when you are reluctant to give it.
>
> This sentiment was earlier expressed in the form honour where honour is due, following the Authorized Version of the Bible: 'Render therefore to all their dues: tribute to whom tribute is due; custom to whom custom; fear to whom fear; honour to whom honour." (Romans 13:7).

If there are any negative connotations associated with the expression "give credit where credit is due," I suspect that they occur as spillover from another very old expression—one in which dislike and grudgingness are obviously present: "give the devil his due." Here is the entry for that phrase in Christine Ammer, *The Facts of File Dictionary of Clichés*, second edition (2006):

> **give the devil his due** Even the bad may deserve some credit. This expression dates from the sixteenth century and was in print by 1589, in *Pappe with an Hatchet*, possibly by John Lyly ("Giue them their due though they were diuels"). Shakespeare used it in several plays, as did John Fletcher, John Dryden, and others. It was a cliché by the time Mark Twain wrote "We must give even Satan his due" (*A Connecticut Yankee in King Arthur's Court*, 1889).

Eric Partridge, *The Routledge Dictionary of Clichés*, fifth edition (1966) confirms this impression:

> **give the Devil his due, to.** To admit an enemy's merits: C. 19–20. A sense-adaptation of the proverbial saying.

Likewise, from *Cambridge International Dictionary of Idioms* (1998):

> **give [somebody] their due, give the devil his due** something that you say when you want to describe someone's good qualities after they have done something wrong or after you have criticized them. [Examples:] *She might be bad at writing letters but I'll give her her due, she always phones me at the end of the month.* [&:] *Geoff usually forgets my birthday, but give the devil his due, he always buys me a lovely Christmas present.*

And finally, from John Ayto, *Oxford Dictionary of English Idioms*, third edition (2009):

> **give the devil his due** if someone or something generally considered bad or undeserving has any redeeming features these should be acknowledged. *proverb*

I think that Colin Fine is correct in seeing a significant split between U.S. and UK understandings of the phrase "give credit where credit is due." In the United States, although the phrase is sometimes used in grudging acknowledgment of the accomplishments of a disliked person or entity, it is more often (in my experience) said neutrally or positively as an expression of simple fairness to whomever deserves commendation. The British sense of the expression, in contrast, seems far closer to the sense of "give the devil his due."

Comment: I've rarely (if ever) heard it in the US when *not* being used in the sense of "give the devil his due".